# How to create a URL frame that displays my vender homepage URL, instead of my website?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, private-members

I'm creating a members only website; my site will give my members access to products at price not available to the general public. These pages need to be private and unsharable and id rather not have to ask my vender to password restrict these pages. A developer suggested URL Frame (masked redirect) which will work, however i would like the url to display my vender homepage address instead of my websites url. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the answer short, no this would be a high security risk and no browser should allow to display other domains in the url bar while still on your site. Something like this would be a high risk for phishing attacks. Imagine you show your own site with the url of a bank login page.